# How to know which functions of a library get called by a program

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

Assume I have binary library (*.so) and a binary program using that library (i.e. I do not own the source code for either).

How can I find out which of the library's functions are called at run time. I would like to know their names, but do not need live info.

Neither of the binaries includes debugging symbols.

Comment: Do you want to know which functions are actually called or which are referred to in the program (the source code contains calls to them, but that source code might not actually execute for some reason)?

Comment: If you're doing static linking (i.e. not dynamically loading symbols from the library after the program starts) then simply link your program, but leave the library files out of the link. The error messages will point to whatever is being used in the library. If your program is dynamically loading any symbols at run time, then it's more difficult (the code can do what it likes if it fails to load from the library, including looking in alternative libraries) - you will either need to examine the source for your code that loads from the library, or find some other way to monitor its behaviour

Comment: I have been hoping that there is something like strace which shows the system calls that are actually issued. But I suppose that has support by the kernel. At least the outlined static analyses will give me a hint at which library functions are not called. This is my actual use case.

Comment: Would [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) help you?

Comment: Does strace show me the function names, with dlsym and without?

Comment: It shows you the function names, when being called. Just try it out.

Comment: I quickly compiled the example from https://gist.github.com/tailriver/30bf0c943325330b7b6a as well as a version of it without dlopen and figured that without any arguments strace doesn't print the libraries function names on my x86_64 platform. Perhaps you have some command line switches in mind?

Comment: Note that you need to fix their makefile to compile it.

Comment: I figured that there is a way to trace called function names with gdb (even if the binaries don't contain debugging symbols: `gdb --args ./dlopen_sample cat` `(gdb) set logging on` `(gdb) set confirm off` `(gdb) rbreak .`. However, that works only if the functions are not called with `dlsym`, so I am still searching.

Answer (score 4):

The [objdump](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) command dumps external symbol references from a binary. The typical use case involves running it with the `-T` option, to dump a binary's external symbol references.

For example, running `objdump -T` on `/bin/ls`:

```
/bin/ls:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3   __ctype_toupper_loc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 getenv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              cap_to_text
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __progname
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 sigprocmask
...
```

And so on. The dump includes all external symbol references, not just functions. The manual page explains the meaning of codes in the 2nd column, that specify the type of the external symbol reference. Here, looks like we'll be interested in `DF`s, indicating dynamic function calls. Here, we see some familiar C library functions, like `getenv()` and `sigprocmask()`, being referenced by `/bin/ls.

Unrecognized library calls are likely the result of internal macros in the header files, using the library's internal implementation details. That's probably what "__ctype_toupper_loc" is all about.

When using this with C++ code you also want to specify the `-C` option, to demangle C++ symbols.

Of course, the fact that a particular binary carries an external reference to some library function doesn't guarantee that the binary will actually call it, at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring (for the moment) the possibility of using `dlopen`/`dlsysm`, you'd normally just use something like `nm a.out` (or whatever your executable's name is).

For C++, you may want to add `--demangle` to demangle C++ names to something at least marginally more readable. You may also want to use `-u` to get only undefined external symbols (this will remove a fair a number of symbols you *probably* don't care about).

If the program is using `dlopen`/`dlsym`, then essentially the only way to know what it links with is to monitor it at run time. It could (for example) open a text file, read in some strings, then use those strings as the names of libraries and functions to link with. Changing that text file could completely change what functions it links with, so you can't really determine this based on the content of the executable itself.

Comment: Is there a way to extract the dlopen/dlsym calls in order to infer how it is used? If dlsym is only used with fixed string arguments, I would have a chance to at least get an idea what happens.